# React Redux using an object in the initialState

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

I have a chat application coded in ReactJS. I want to make a redux function to add to a list of chats and messages. Hard to explain but here's the code. This is the shortened version of the code. I removed many things that were unrelated so that this code would be easier to read.

```
import {
    CHAT_UPDATE
} from '../actions/types'

const initialState = {
    conversations: {
        "jack": [
            {
                "sender": "jack",
                "text": "This is hard coded",
                "date": "00:00:00 MN | May 5"
            },
            {
                "sender": "administrator",
                "text": "Noted",
                "date": "00:00:01 AM | May 5"
            }
        ]
    }
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CHAT_UPDATE:
            return {
                ...state,
                conversations: {
                    // HELP
                }
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

How do I make an update function so that if an action of `CHAT_UPDATE` is dispatched, - which contains the information of the requested chat and the new message - it will add it to the list of conversations?

For example when this is dispatched:

```
dispatch({
    type: CHAT_UPDATE,
    name: 'jack',
    coversation: {
        "sender": "jack",
        "text": "How's your day?",
        "date": "00:00:02 AM | May 5"
    }
})
```

I want the new state to be

```
conversations: {
    "jack": [
        {
            "sender": "jack",
            "text": "This is hard coded",
            "date": "00:00:00 MN | May 5"
        },
        {
            "sender": "administrator",
            "text": "Noted",
            "date": "00:00:01 AM | May 5"
        },
        {
            "sender": "jack",
            "text": "How's your day?",
            "date": "00:00:02 AM | May 5"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work!!

```
return {
    ...state,
   conversations: {
       ...state.converstation,
       [action.name]: [
           ...state.converstation[action.name],
           {
               ...action.coversation
           }
       ]
   }
}
```

Comment: or you can do

[action.name]: [...state.conversation[action.name], action.conversation]

Answer (score 0):

You should update it in this way

```
return {
 ...state,
 [
   ...state[action.name],
   action.coversation,
 ]
}
```